# Combining XPath selector in selenium IDE

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm looking for a way to combine 2 XPath selectors into 1 to use in Selenium IDE, so I can check if an element with a certain ID has a certain class.

These 2 selectors do work but aren't narrowing enough to do an assertElementPresent on.

```
xpath= .//*[contains (@class,'ui-tabs-hide')]
xpath= .//*[@id='${newTableID}']
```

I've unsuccesfully tried following XPath

```
xpath= .//*[contains (@class,'ui-tabs-hide')]/*[@id='${newTableID}']
```

Can anyone help me out on this one please?

Thanks,

J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
xpath=.//*[@id='${newTableID}' 
        and contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' ui-tabs-hide ')]
```

**Do note how `contains()` is specified**. This guarantees that elements with classnames having the wanted class name as prefix or as suffix, will not be selected.

Answer (score 2):

Okay... x-mass is still making my head a bit fuzzy...

```
xpath=.//*[@id='${newTableID}' and contains (@class,'ui-tabs-hide')]
```

was the way to go